# What affects the rate of filling the Power Bar?

Tags: temple-run-2

Naturally I want to fill the Power Bar as fast as possible, and from just the basics I can see:

- The bar seems to fill when picking up coins
- There are purchasable upgrades, which increase the rate that it charges

I'm most curious if the 2x and 3x coins fill it at 2x or 3x the rate, if the amount of "points" to fill it are always the same, and similar nuances like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all,**
The Power-Up bar fills *only* when you collect coins. You are mistaken.

**Also,**
When you buy an upgrade, let's say,

> The Power-Up bar fills 10% faster.

That means you will require 10% **less** coins to fill it up.

### EDIT

Yes, when you collect **2x** and **3x** coins (through Power-Up *or* Pickup Spawn), your bar fills up 2x and 3x times faster.
Although, the total number of coins that needs to be collected remains the same *without upgrading*.

Comment: +1 For correcting me on the "running" source of power-up.  I could swear I had seen that before, but I must have fooled myself.  Beyond that, I'm really interested in the 2x and 3x coins aspect.  Do you have any info on that?

Comment: And the total value of coins, not the total number of coins, required for a full meter is always the same.